# Using stand-alone Obfsproxy in OSX

Tags: vpn, mac, obfsproxy, openvpn

There are many different [applications](https://community.openvpn.net/openvpn/wiki/TrafficObfuscation) that try to bypass censorship by Obfsproxy, but in OSX, how we can communicate with Obfsproxy as we can easily do in Linux? Terminal says -bash: obfsproxy: command not found

Also, how can I ask Obfsproxy to use a socks proxy before connecting to the server? in TBB's GUI, I can set proxy rules but in stand-alone Obfsproxy, I have no idea.